# How to stream archived media files?

Tags: linux, html, streaming

I've got lot of archives that contains podcasts. Actually they're in ZIP archives, one archive is about *200Mb* and contains 9/10 **MP3** files. I'm running a root access Linux server and the main problem is the disk-space.

I'd like to build a small web page (in **PHP** or **Python**) where:

- The user can **download** the whole archives (that's ok, if i keep
  archive files).
- The user can **play** file through an HTML5 player (but without keep
  extracted files).

So the answer: **is possible to stream archived files?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the server has disk space limitations, you definitely cannot achieve what you're asking because even if the user doesn't download and extract it the server will.

I'd suggest you just convert the video to a smaller format flv (flash) or other.

Plus, although videos are not 'archives' they are compressed:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression#Video_quality
and
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_codecs

Comment: Hmm... I was think something different.. Like `$handle = popen('/bin/unzip -p myfile.zip file002.mp3 2>&1', 'r');` then `fread` and `pclose`. That's impossible? (note: there are only audio MP3 files).